# RelativeLayout with scrollview not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I'm working on fixing a bug in someone's code and I can't figure out how to get this to scroll correctly. I'm just trying to get the "question" area to scroll vertically. Currently it just grows and pushes everything down. Please help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:slide="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.trivia.americanhistory"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#000000">
    <Button android:id="@+id/ned_icon" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ned_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/menu" android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ned_icon" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/share"
        android:background="@drawable/share_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/ned_character_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/ned_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ned_character_image"
            android:src="@drawable/ned"
            android:padding="2dp" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_height="140dp" android:layout_width="106dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/question_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/question_bkgrd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_below="@+id/ned_icon"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/q"
            android:background="@drawable/q_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />
        <ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/q" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="150dp">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/question"
                android:text="Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a "
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/q" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="150dp" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" />
        </ScrollView>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/amount_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/plain_dollar_amt_bkgr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ned_character_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="40dp" android:id="@+id/skull"
            android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/skull" android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/level_text" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:text="Level 0"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/skull" android:text="Question 1/40"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"   android:id="@+id/question_number"/>


    </RelativeLayout>



    <Button android:id="@+id/call_mama"
        android:background="@drawable/call_mama"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/answer_a_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:onClick="callMama" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/call_nina"
        android:background="@drawable/call_nina"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/answer_a_layout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/call_mama"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" android:onClick="fiftyFifty" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/call_jed"
        android:background="@drawable/call_jed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/answer_a_layout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/call_nina"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/answer_a_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
        <Button android:background="@drawable/ans_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
        <Button android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/answer_a_mark" android:background="@drawable/cross"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView android:layout_margin="5dp" android:id="@+id/answer_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/answer_a_line"
        android:background="@drawable/question_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answer_a_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/answer_b_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answer_a_line"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
        <Button android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ans_b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/answer_b_mark" android:background="@drawable/cross"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView android:layout_margin="5dp" android:id="@+id/answer_b"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/answer_b_line"
        android:background="@drawable/question_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answer_b_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/answer_c_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answer_b_line"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
        <Button android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ans_c"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cross" android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/answer_c_mark" />
        <TextView android:layout_margin="5dp" android:id="@+id/answer_c"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/answer_c_line"
        android:background="@drawable/question_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answer_c_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/answer_d_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answer_c_line"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
        <Button android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ans_d"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/answer_d_mark" android:background="@drawable/cross"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView android:layout_margin="5dp" android:id="@+id/answer_d"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/answer_d_line"
        android:background="@drawable/question_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answer_d_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <Button android:layout_margin="10dp" android:id="@+id/flag_it"
        android:background="@drawable/flag_it"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answer_d_line" />
    <TextView android:layout_margin="10dp" android:id="@+id/count_down"
        android:text="29" android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag_it"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answer_d_line"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button android:layout_margin="10dp" android:id="@+id/next_question"
        android:background="@drawable/next_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answer_d_line"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/count_down" />


    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip" android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/ads" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" slide:backgroundColor="#000000"
            slide:textColor="#ffffff" slide:testing="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            slide:keywords="Android applications "
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you set the height of the `ScrollView` to `wrap_content`. Try giving it a fixed height or using a `LinearLayout` with weight so it fills the space left over from the other views.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to set it to a specific height, you can also add

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

to your `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll view doesn't have any problem.
But, You can not see your scroll bar because your textview has too short text.

Update your code like below.

Scroll bar will be shown up when contents are long than yours automatically.

Good luck, Josh!

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height= " fill_parent "
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/q" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="150dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/question"
        android:text="Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a Test annswer a ....."
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/q" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" />
</ScrollView>
```