# scrollview doesn't scroll android in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am really new in using the scrollView so please be patient with me:)

I am trying to make an whole view of a scrollView but the scrollView doesn't scroll.

Here is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/general_form_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/form_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/myWebView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/FirstNameRegister"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myWebView"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:editable="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Full name"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:text="+" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/myProgressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myWebView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="84dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/PhoneRegister"
                android:layout_width="205dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/EmailRegister"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:editable="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="phone"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EmailRegister"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/myWebView"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myWebView"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:editable="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/DialZonePhoneRegister"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/myWebView"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myWebView"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:editable="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="3344"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true" >
            </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SubmitRegisterButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/EmailRegister"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/s" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me with it:)

Comment: Where is your code? :)

Comment: I edit the post and insert the code:) Please have a look

Comment: just change the RelativeLayout's(id:form_layout) height from match_parent to wrap_content

Comment: I edit my code and make changes, Anyway, the scrollview is not working. I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the layout params of form_layout to be like this :

```
 android:id="@+id/form_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:padding="10dp" >
```

In other words, the layout height have to be wrap_content.
If the height is set to match_parent, then it will fill the height of the screen from parent layout and it will not cover the extra elements that are located above the screen height.

Comment: Hello, I have 2 relativeLayout. Which one do i have to add :   android:layout_height="wrap_content" ? the first one or second one?

Comment: I edit my code and make changes, Anyway, the scrollview is not working. I can't see it.

Comment: The inner relative layout

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code For Both Scrollbars..On Table Layout.

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"> 
     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


     <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

    </TableLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or Use this link for Scrollbar On [relative Layout..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321063/relativelayout-with-scrollview-not-scrolling)

Comment: Hi, I need the scrollview to be vertical, not horizontal. I do not need of tableLayout too.. Can u please be more specific about my specific case? Many thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on RelativeLayout, it has to have a height to wrap_content because it needs to be as big as its content for scrollview to know how much to scroll.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/form_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" >
```

Comment: Hello, I have 2 relativeLayout. Which one do i have to add : android:layout_height="wrap_content" ? the first one or second one?

Comment: I edit my code and make changes, Anyway, the scrollview is not working. I can't see it.

Comment: the one with the id="@+id/form_layout"

Answer (score 0):

REmove this line from your Button

```
android:layout_below="@+id/EmailRegister"
```

Run App and See Scroll Or Not, Not then Scrollview Put on root layout and then relative layout

```
Scrollview -> RelativeLayout
```

like this and Run App, Not Scroll Then Change Scrollview To NestedScrollview